# How do I output each row in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, twilio-programmable-chat

The objective of this code is to print out some column values as it lists out the number of days. The output I am getting is the column value for the first day.

```
days = final_merged_data['Day'].tolist()
for day in days:
    each_row = final_merged_data[final_merged_data['Day'] == days]

    message_partition = f"""
    [{day}]
    Solar_Power_Generated in MW = {str(each_row['Power_Solar'].tolist()[0])}
    Wind_Power_Generated in MW = {str(each_row['Power_Wind'].tolist()[0])}
    Total_Power_Generated in MW = {str(each_row['Total MW'].tolist()[0])}"""
    
print(message_partition)
```

The output I am getting is the same column value for row 1.

```
[12]
    Solar_Power_Generated in MW = 26.48
    Wind_Power_Generated in MW = 30.34
    Total_Power_Generated in MW = 56.82
[13]
    Solar_Power_Generated in MW = 26.48
    Wind_Power_Generated in MW = 30.34
    Total_Power_Generated in MW = 56.82
```

````
       Day  Unnamed: 0.1  Temp_Hi  Temp_Low  Cloud  Solar  Month  windspeed  Direction  Rainfall  Power_Solar  Power_Wind
    0   16           0.0    29.44     29.01    1.0  12.24    9.0      11.50      225.0      4.98       0.3500       33.55
    1   17           1.0    29.47     28.85    3.0  12.54    9.0      10.64      223.0      3.55       1.0100       31.56
    2   18           2.0    29.60     28.89   51.0  12.87    9.0      10.44      224.0      4.00      16.8900       31.70
    3   19           3.0    29.37     29.12  100.0  11.99    9.0      11.32      227.0      5.16       0.6618       34.13
    4   20           4.0    29.32     28.90   42.0  12.50    9.0      12.18      230.0      3.50      13.9100       36.53
    5   21           5.0    29.25     28.67   75.0  13.23    9.0      11.97      228.0      2.92      24.8300       35.42
    6   22           6.0    29.14     28.56   66.0  12.57    9.0      11.71      229.0      1.47      21.8500       35.48
    7   23           7.0    29.32     28.66   43.0  12.45    9.0      12.37      226.0      0.11       7.1200       35.13```
````

Comment: Please provide samples for input which needs to be parsed for the expected output.

Comment: Your print statement is outside of the loop. Maybe thats it already. If not, please provide more information on the input and expected output.

Comment: For indexing, you're using a comparison [final_merged_data['Day'] == days], which is resulting in False always. The list index becomes equivalent to final_merged_data[0], hence always first row data is displayed.

Comment: @windstorm I already declared it with days = final_merged_data['Day'].tolist()

Comment: @tst. I moved the print statement into the loop but got the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for a dictionary of columns:

```
rows = final_merged_data.tolist()
for row in rows:
    message_partition = f"""
    [{row['Day']}]
    Solar_Power_Generated in MW = {str(row['Power_Solar'])}
    Wind_Power_Generated in MW = {str(row['Power_Wind'])}
    Total_Power_Generated in MW = {str(row['Total MW'])}"""
    
    print(message_partition)
```

Alternatively, if all columns are stored as lists in a dict,

```
rows = zip(final_merged_data['Day'].tolist(), final_merged_data['Power_Solar'].tolist(), final_merged_data['Power_Wind'].tolist(), final_merged_data['Total MW'].tolist())

for row in rows:
    message_partition = f"""
    [{row[0]}]
    Solar_Power_Generated in MW = {str(row[1])}
    Wind_Power_Generated in MW = {str(row[2])}
    Total_Power_Generated in MW = {str(row[3])}"""
    
    print(message_partition)
```

Comment: Thanks @ windstorm. The second solution worked just fine. Thanks to you, I have learned something new.